# Populating columns with a different name in Python

Tags: python

I have two columns in a dataset. (screenshot attached as a sample) One contains the location and the other place(initially blank) - I want to write a python program so that the location helps in populating the place after the programming is done.

[Sample picture for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODfGa.png)

If the location is 'Atlanta', the place should be 'South' and if it is 'Illinois', the place should be 'Mid-West'.
There are 1000 different locations in my original dataset, and I am only categorizing them into three different place info.

How do I do it?

Comment: Where is the relationship between locations and places? Is this a dictionary?

Comment: These are just two columns in a dataset. I created three lists and tried to iterate over them, but it did not work. Did I answer your question?

Comment: How do you know that Atlanta is related with South? How will computer know about it? Is there any data structure that has all these relationships?

Comment: I think I understand your question now. In order to create such a relationship, do I create a dictionary or multiple dictionaries? How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You can create a dictionary like this: `{'Atlanta': 'South', 'Illinois': 'Mid-West', ...etc}` or a dataframe with locations in one column and places in another one, but this is pretty what your original question is about

Comment: In my original dataset, I have 18 columns and 1200 rows, but with these two columns, in location, I have 20 different unique values, which I need to categorize into three categories in the column place. When I have 'Atlanta' : 'South'  in the dictionary, how do I categorize Miami to South as well?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What results/errors are you getting?

Comment: I created three(since I have three categories) different lists with different locations and tried to parallel traverse in the list. I know that I am wrong because I am getting true and false